# Laravel+React integrate Stripe payment gateway simple example pricing cards

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, stripe-payments, inertiajs

I am integrating Stripe payment gateway in React Laravel Inertia please provide me a simple example to integrate Stripe payment I have pricing cards and a Chose plan button I want when I click on the Choose plan button if the user exists it takes into Stripe payment gateway otherwise it take into login page

Here is my code

```
    import Navbar from "@/Components/Wesite/Navbar";
import Carousal from "@/Components/Wesite/Carousel";
import Cards from "@/Components/Wesite/Cards";
import { Link, Head, usePage } from "@inertiajs/react";
import PricingCard from "@/Components/Wesite/Pricing";
import FooterBrand from "@/Components/Wesite/Footer";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Welcome(props) {

    const { image, memberships } = usePage().props;

    const { class_3, class_4, class_5, phone, message, location } = image;

    const [membershipCards, setMemberShipCards] = useState(memberships);

    return (
        <>
            <Head title="Home" />
            <div className="h-screen  bg-gray-900">
                <section className="">
                    <Navbar props={props} />
                </section>
                <section className="h-full w-full bg-gray-900">
                    <div className="relative h-full">
                        <Carousal props={image} />
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section className="w-full bg-gray-900">
                    <div className="text-center p-10">
                        <div className="uppercase text-theme-orange text-2xl font-[700]">
                            Why Chose us ?
                        </div>
                        <div className="uppercase text-white text-[32px] font-[600]">
                            PUSH YOUR LIMITS FORWARD
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container h-full mx-auto p-10">
                        <div className="w-full flex gap-3 flex-auto">
                            <Cards
                                props={class_3}
                                title="Modern equipment"
                                description="
                                Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                            />
                            <Cards
                                props={class_4}
                                title="Healthy nutrition plan"
                                description="
                                Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                            />
                            <Cards
                                props={class_5}
                                title="Proffesponal training plan"
                                description=" Exercise equipment is any apparatus or device used during physical activity to enhance the strength or conditioning effects of that exercise by providing either fixed or adjustable amounts of resistance, or to otherwise enhance the experience or outcome of an exercise routine."
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section className="w-full bg-gray-900">
                    <div className="text-center p-10">
                        <div className="uppercase text-theme-orange text-2xl font-[700]">
                            OUR PLAN
                        </div>
                        <div className="uppercase text-white text-[32px] font-[600]">
                            CHOOSE YOUR PRICING PLAN
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container mx-auto p-10">
                        <div className="w-full flex gap-3 flex-grow justify-evenly">

                            {membershipCards.map((item, index) =>
                                <PricingCard key={index} id={item.id} name={item.name} price={item.price} description={item.description} duration={item.duration} />

                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section className="w-full bg-gray-900 text-white">
                    <div className="container flex justify-between p-5 mx-auto">
                        <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img src={location} alt="" width="65px" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                333 Middle Winchendon Rd, Rindge, NH 03461
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img src={phone} alt="" width="65px" />
                            </div>
                            <div>125-711-811 125-668-886</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img src={message} alt="" width="65px" />
                            </div>
                            <div>Support.gymcenter@gmail.com</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <FooterBrand />
                </section>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { Card } from "flowbite-react";
import { useState } from "react";

let PricingCard = ({ id, name, price, description, duration }) => {

    const [planId, setPlanId] = useState({
        membership_plan_id: id,
    })
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // axios.get('/member/buy-subscription', planId);
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <h5 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                {name}
            </h5>
            <div className="flex items-baseline text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                <span className="text-3xl font-semibold">$</span>
                <span className="text-5xl font-extrabold tracking-tight">
                    {price}
                </span>
                <span className="ml-1 text-xl font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    /{duration} month
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="my-7 space-y-5">
                <div className="w-[300px]">

                    {description}
                </div>
            </div>


            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="hidden" name="membership_plan_id" value={planId.id} />
                <button
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-lg bg-theme-orange px-5 py-2.5 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-theme-orange focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-cyan-200 dark:focus:ring-cyan-900"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    <p>Choose plan</p>
                </button>
            </form>
        </Card>
    );
};
export default PricingCard;
```

//Laravel controller method

```
 public function buySubScription(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            dd($request->all());
        } else {
            return to_route('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: this would be helpful for you: https://lonare.medium.com/stripe-with-react-native-frontend-and-laravel-8-backend-without-cashier-simple-step-by-step-9fa48038f879

Comment: it is react native i need in react